# boost python - how to send a raw pointer to a python function>

Tags: c++, python, pointers, boost-python

I have python embedded in my application and I want to send a python function a raw pointer to an object I have in my C++ code.
The only way I found how to do this is to wrap the pointer with an `auto_ptr` or a `shared_ptr` but I prefer not to do that since I don't want the python code to have any chance of holding a reference to the object in my code.

Is this possible with boost::python?

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/a/5056462/138772 has your solution. "Pass the object pointer via boost::python::ptr to python. This will prevent the python interpreter from making a copy".

Comment: @JAB Nice! Write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually, it seems I didn't look into it enough/didn't read what I copied and pasted properly. It looks like using `boost::python::ptr` will actually make the possibility of dangling references _more_ likely, as according to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/v2/ptr.html, "Normally, when passing pointers to Python callbacks, the pointee is copied to ensure that the Python object never holds a dangling reference."

Answer (score 0):

If you have raw pointer to some C++ object mapped into Python then you can make another Python object around original pointer using adapter in such way:

```
template<typename PtrT>
struct PtrAdapter {
    auto& get(PtrT ptr)  { return *ptr; }
};
```

Then make it's Python mapped type and allow implicit conversion:

```
class_<Cluster<LinksT>*, noncopyable>(typpedName<LinksT>("ClusterPtr", true, true)
, "Raw hierarchy cluster pointer\n")
    .def("__call__", &PtrAdapter<Cluster<LinksT>*>::get,
        return_internal_reference<>(),
        "referenced cluster")
    ;
register_ptr_to_python<Cluster<LinksT>*>();
```

Note that referenced type (in this case `Cluster<LinksT>`) also must be mapped to the appropriate Python object.
Then for such C++ code:

```
Cluster<LinksT>* cl = clusters.head();
process(cl);
Id cid = cl->id();
```

You can use similar Python code:

```
cl = clusters.head()
process(cl)
cid = cl.id()
```

But if you don't need some **special processing** of pointer to C++ object then it's obviously better to use `boost::python::ptr`.
Also you should consider alternatives mentioned here: [boost::python: howto call a function that expects a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881457/boostpython-howto-call-a-function-that-expects-a-pointer)