# Boost python C++ class having constructor taking default argument Null pointer as parameter

Tags: python, pointers, boost, arguments, default

Can someone please help me in knowing how to extend a class which has a constructor taking required and default arguments and one of the default argument is a void pointer?

eg:

```
class A
{
    A(int a, int b, void* c=NULL):...
    {
    }
}

class_<A>("A").def(init<int, init, optional</*What should I write for argument c*/>>
;
```

I got the answer. It should be straight away I have to specify the type of default variable. Thus in this case it should be `optional<void*>`. 
But can someone help me in writing Python equivalent code illustrating how to specify pointer argument from Python to C++ using wrapper written above?

Comment: This looks like a case of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881457/boostpython-howto-call-a-function-that-expects-a-pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881457/boostpython-howto-call-a-function-that-expects-a-pointer)